# C- Fix Stack overflow in Recursion

Tags: c, exception, recursion, stack, overflow

A code in C to find maximum of an array using divide and conquer but it keeps throwing 
"stack overflow exception" . Help would be appreciated!

```
int a[10];
int find(int l,int h)
{
    int x;

    if(h==0)
    {
        x=0;
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        if(h==1)
        {
            if(a[0]>a[1])
            {
                x=0;
                return x;
            }
            else
            {
                x=1;
                return x;
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            int mid,z,y;
            mid=(l+h)/2;
            y=find(0,mid);
            z=find(mid+1,h);
            if(a[y]<a[z])
            {
                x=z;
            }
            else
            {
                x=y;
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

There are only limited variables and I don't see where the function can go into an infinite recursion.

```
int main()
{
    int i,n,max,min,ans;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    ans=find(0,n-1);

    printf("the maximum element is- %d\n",ans);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your stopping condition when `h` is `0` or `1` catch all the cases, if not then it will keep re-cursing infinitely.

Comment: There's something odd with your algorithm, consider `l = 0` and `h = 2`: `mid = (0+2)/2 = 1; y=find(0,1); z=find(2,2);` - Which looks correct but then look what the `find(2,2)` will do: `mid = (2+2)/2 = 2; y=find(0,2);`  <= We're back at our first test values. `z=find(3,2);`  <= This just looks odd.

Comment: I guess this is an attempt to use divide and conquer to calculate finding the maximum element?

Comment: Yes, my bad. it is to find max position!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where you call `find(0, 2)`. Since `h > 1`, you enter the second `else` clause, and `mid` is `1`. Then on the second recursive call, it is to `find(2, 2)`. On this recursive call, you again enter the second `else`, since `h` is still 2. But the `mid` is also `2`. Now, the first recursive call goes to `find(0, 2)`, which enters an infinite loop.

```
find(0, 2)
   h not 0
       h not 1
           mid = 1
           find(0, 1)
           find(2, 2)
               h not 0
                   h not 1
                       mid = 2
                       find (0, 2) <-- loop
```

It seems the intention of the `if` checks on `h` is to prevent the `mid` calculation from being the same as `l`. If so, then you can calculate the `mid` variable at the top of your function, and use that as the stopping condition.

It looks like this is an attempt to use divide and conquer to locate the position of the maximum element in the array `a`. If so, then your first recursive call should restrict itself to the range of `[l..mid]` instead of going back to `0`.

Putting it all together:

```
int find(int l,int h)
{
    int mid = (l+h)/2;

    if (mid == l)
    {
        return (a[l] > a[h]) ? l : h;
    }
    else
    {
        int y = find(l, mid);
        int z = find(mid+1, h);
        return (a[y] > a[z]) ? y : z;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: `a` is a global in the asker's question. It gets initialized by `main`.

Comment: my bad, I was inattentive. deleting my coment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified, which is running successfully..
The problem is that you weren't checking the difference between `l` and `h` but only the value of `h`...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[10];


int find(int l,int h)
{
int x;



if(h-l==0)
{

    return h;
}
else
{


    if(h-l==1)
    {
        if(a[l]>a[l+1])
        {

            return l;
        }
        else
            {

                return l+1;
            }
    }
    else
    { 
        int mid,z,y;
        mid=(l+h)/2;
        y=find(0,mid);
        z=find(mid+1,h);



        if(a[y]<a[z])
        {
            x=z;
        }
        else
        {
            x=y;
        }

        return x;
    }}}
int main()
{
a[0]=3;
a[1]=7;
a[2]=5;
cout<<find(0,2)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using wrong conditions, try:

```
first if: if(h==l)

second if: if(h-l==1)

third if:  
      if(a[h]>a[l])  {
         return h;
      } else {
         return l;
      }
```